# TMS in UTM grid with MapProxy & OpenLayers 4?

Tags: geoserver, openlayers, mapproxy

I am trying to cache a GeoServer layer with MapProxy and display it on an OpenLayers4 map. I created a new MapProxy grid in UTM32N and in the MapProxy preview the layer is shown nicely, but when I add it to my ol map, it won't display at all. Requests are sent but return empty tiles.

I have tried several grid definitions, two are shown below ("utm32n" and "germany") in the mapproxy config:

```
services:
  demo:
  tms:
    use_grid_names: true
    origin: 'sw'

layers:
  - name: mylayer
    title: mytitle
    sources: [mysource]
caches:
  mylayer:
    grids: [webmercator, germany]
    sources: [mysource]

sources:
  mylayer:
    type: wms
    req:
      url: http://mygeoserver/ws/wms
      layers: mylayer
      transparent: true

grids:
    utm32n:
        srs: EPSG:25832
        bbox: [239323.44497139292,4290144.074117256,760676.555028607,9503675.174689397]
        bbox_srs: EPSG:25832
        origin: sw
        min_res: 156367.7919628329
        num_levels: 18
    germany:
      srs: 'EPSG:25832'
      bbox: [6, 47.3, 15.1, 55]
      bbox_srs: 'EPSG:4326'
      origin: 'sw'
```

In my ol map, I have tried to define the layer as ol.source.TileImage:

```
var extent = ol.proj.transformExtent([6, 47.3, 15.1, 55], "EPSG:4326", epsg_code);
var size = ol.extent.getWidth(extent) / 256;
var no_zoomlevels = map.getView().getMaxZoom() - map.getView().getMinZoom() + 1;
var resolutions = new Array(no_zoomlevels);
for(var i=map.getView().getMinZoom(); i<=map.getView().getMaxZoom(); i++){
    resolutions[i] = map.getView().getResolutionForZoom(i);
}
var layer = new ol.layer.Tile({
    name: name,
    source: new ol.source.TileImage({
        projection: epsg_code,
        tileGrid: new ol.tilegrid.TileGrid({
            resolutions: resolutions,
            extent: extent,
            origin: [extent[0], extent[1]],
            minZoom: map.getView().getMinZoom(),
        }),
        tileUrlFunction: function(tileCoord, pixelRatio, projection){
            var z = tileCoord[0];
            var x = tileCoord[1];
            var y = - tileCoord[2];
            var url = 'http://mymapproxy/tms/1.0.0/mylayer/germany/' + z + '/' + x + '/' + y + '.png';
            return url;
        }
    }),
});
```

as well as ol.source.XYZ:

```
...
source: new ol.source.XYZ({
    url: 'http://mymapproxy/tms/1.0.0/' + name + '/germany/{z}/{x}/{-y}.png',
    projection: epsg_code,
    minZoom: map.getView().getMinZoom(),
    maxZoom: map.getView().getMaxZoom(),
}),
...
```

It seems like the ol grid and the mapproxy grid are not the same, but how do I match them?

Answer (score 2):

I finally made it work with this configuration:

I put the transformed **bbox** into the grid-definition and set the **min_res** to the openlayers-resolution of zoom level 0 in **mapproxy.yaml**:

```
grids:
  germany:
    srs: 'EPSG:25832'
    bbox: [273211.2532533697, 5242868.243936263, 961083.6232988155, 6111822.37943825]
    origin: 'sw'
    min_res: 156367.7919628329
    num_levels: 18
```

In my **ol map**, I defined the source like this (**extent** and **resolutions** are exactly the same as in mapproxy):

```
var extent = [273211.2532533697, 5242868.243936263, 961083.6232988155, 6111822.37943825];
var resolutions = [];
for(var i=map.getView().getMinZoom(); i<=map.getView().getMaxZoom(); i++){
  resolutions[i] = map.getView().getResolutionForZoom(i);
}
var source = new ol.source.TileImage({
  projection: 'EPSG:25832',
  tileGrid: new ol.tilegrid.TileGrid({
    resolutions: resolutions,
    extent: extent,
    origin: [extent[0], extent[1]],
    minZoom: map.getView().getMinZoom(),
  }),
  tileUrlFunction: function(tileCoord, pixelRatio, projection){
    var z = tileCoord[0];
    var x =  tileCoord[1];
    var y =  tileCoord[2];
    var url = 'http://mymapproxy/tms/1.0.0/mylayer/germany/' + z + '/' + x + '/' + y + '.png';
    return url;
  },
});
```

Probably there are other ways and I still don't understand completely how these grids work, but I set my focus on synchronizing the two grids. Apparently, the transformation of mapproxy & openlayers/proj4js is not exactly the same, as the grid was slightly shifted before I defined the extent directly in UTM coordinates (calculated by ol/proj4).

I hope, this might help someone with similar problems sometime...